# How to export Database from MSFT SQL Server to Oracle Database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration

i have ssms server and i am working in that now i have created 21 million data now i want shift that database to oracle data base i installed oracle server but i dont know how to transfter database ssms to oracle can anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

SSMS is just a program you use to manage/query/use SQL Server.

What you want to do is migrate 22,000,000 rows to Oracle Database.

One thing you can do is use the MSFT bcp utility to unload that data to delimited text files.

Then, use the SQLLoader utility from Oracle, to load that data into your Oracle Database, and the table you have for it.

We have a migration utility that helps you do this, it's called Oracle SQL Developer.

I wrote [a white paper with step by step instructions](https://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/migrating-to-oracle-database-wp-3610526.pdf) for Sybase ASE, but the steps are identical for SQL Server.

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and I am the product manager for SQL Developer.*